# Creating grouped/stacked bar plot in R gives error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a grouped/stacked bar plot in R which looks like this plot:
[image: Stacked bar plot]

I have the data:

| misery_dif | choice | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -5 | choice A | 56 |
| -5 | choice B | 1 |
| -4 | choice A | 32 |
| -4 | choice B | 12 |
| -3 | choice A | 153 |
| -3 | choice B | 23 |
| -2 | choice A | 398 |
| -2 | choice B | 120 |
| -1 | choice A | 196 |
| -1 | choice B | 77 |
| 0 | choice A | 318 |
| 0 | choice B | 334 |
| 1 | choice A | 235 |
| 1 | choice B | 316 |
| 2 | choice A | 76 |
| 2 | choice B | 347 |
| 3 | choice A | 45 |
| 3 | choice B | 159 |
| 4 | choice A | 5 |
| 4 | choice B | 96 |

I run the code:

```
ggplot(DCE, aes(x=as.character(misery_diff), y=number, fill=choice)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

But got an error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My questions are: 1) Is it the right code to get this graph? 2) What is wrong with the code I run?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please post `dput(DCE)` not a picture, so others can reproduce your issue

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I posted the data like a table.

Comment: Your code works fine on your data.

Comment: I have run it again and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your data. In your table you have `misery_dif`, but on your code in the question you have `misery_diff`, typo there?

```
df <-
tibble::tribble(
  ~misery_dif,    ~choice, ~number,
           -5, "choice A",      56,
           -5, "choice B",       1,
           -4, "choice A",      32,
           -4, "choice B",      12,
           -3, "choice A",     153,
           -3, "choice B",      23,
           -2, "choice A",     398,
           -2, "choice B",     120,
           -1, "choice A",     196,
           -1, "choice B",      77,
            0, "choice A",     318,
            0, "choice B",     334,
            1, "choice A",     235,
            1, "choice B",     316,
            2, "choice A",      76,
            2, "choice B",     347,
            3, "choice A",      45,
            3, "choice B",     159,
            4, "choice A",       5,
            4, "choice B",      96
  )
```

This is a plot of the simple counts

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(misery_dif), number, fill=choice))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

This is not what you want but can help you understand what's going on.

> Notice that I use `factor()` and not `as.character()`. Factor is what you want, so that R understands that this is a numeric factor with specific levels.

Now calculate the percentage and modify the levels of choices to match your expected output.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(misery_dif) %>% 
  mutate(percent = number/sum(number),
         choice = factor(choice, levels =c("choice B", "choice A"))) %>%
# now plot the thing 
  ggplot(aes(factor(misery_dif), percent, fill=choice))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray80", "black")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent())+
  labs(x="Distance from misery indexes between A and B", y="")
```

[image]